# NFC Chip is not activated in lockscreen after Nexus S update to ICS

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nfc, lockscreen

i am having trouble with my app on nexus s after updating to ics.
My app reads all RFID-tags scanned while the lockscreen is activated (it's about getting the rfid-serial-number).
This worked out well on 2.3.6.

- start app
- put device in sleep mode
- logcat-message from NfcService: "NFC-C OFF, disconnect"
- wake up the device by pressing the power button
- logcat-message from NfcService: "NFC-C ON"
- tag is read by the device without unlocking the lockscreen, show notification in status bar / play sound
- put device back in sleep mode

So after the update, i wake up the device from sleep, but nfc is not turned back on!
I have to unlock the device to be able to read tags... is there any workaround so i can read my tags while the device is locked?

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct: NFC is not turned on before the screen is unlocked. I think it was actually an oversight that it was turned on before that in previous versions. I heard of quite a few people who had their public transport card and Nexus S phone in the same pocket. They reported many "unknown tag" notifications in the Tags app on Gingerbread when they would unlock their phone.

I think the only way to disable this is to build your own Android custom firmware that re-enables the old behaviour.